# How to convert a base64 image to an image and save it to the file system

Tags: python, image, save, converters

I have a string:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjwAAAJbCAIAAABvnNkvAAAACXBIWXM и т.д.
```

Full:https://pastebin.com/tfDThBnE

How to convert to png and jpg and save this image in the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import base64
from io import BytesIO

data = 'copy_your_raw_data_here'
# you need to remove the prefix 'data:image/png;base64,'

bytes_decoded = base64.b64decode(data)


img = Image.open(BytesIO(bytes_decoded))
img.show()

# to jpg
out_jpg = img.convert("RGB")

# save file
out_jpg.save("saved_img.jpg")
```

if you don't have PIL(Pillow) library, make sure install it first.

```
pip install pillow
```

It is a python imgae handler package.